# I need a Regex expression that will stop anything that is not 3 (or more) letter word?

Tags: java, regex, eclipse

In  my code I want anything that isn't a three (or more) letter word to go into the while loop and anything else to continue into the code. I am not that confident with Regex and would like help on how to fix it.

```
    while (!(word.matches("(a-z){3,}")))
    {
        System.out.println("You have not entered in a valid word (it has to be at least 3 letters long).");

        System.out.println();

        System.out.print("Please enter a word of your choice: ");
        word = keyboard.nextLine();

    }
```

N.B. This is for homework

Comment: can you just use string.length?

Comment: while(word.length < 3)

Comment: `(a-z)` should be `[A-z]`, `(a-z)` will only match `a-z` but you can just say `\w{0,3}` this will match all collections of letter characters with a length of 3 or less I know regex is super confusing at first but you will get it, I used regexr.com a lot while I was still learning

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak Thanks, and for words with 3 or more letters would you do \w{3,} ?

Comment: yep, `\w{3,}` also that should be `\w{1,3}` I had a brainfart

Comment: @JohnKane I also want to check if it is a word and my teacher prefers if I do it in one Regex condition

Comment: @red_star_12 I let you see below the answer explaining it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `[a-z]` whiich means a char between `a` and `z`, rather than `(a-z)` which means match exactly `"a-z"`

---

- You'd better `\w` class that represents word-character  = `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`
- `\w` **=** a letter between `a` and `z` OR bewtween `A` and `Z` OR between `0` and `9`, or a `_`

**==>** [`regex demo`](https://regex101.com/r/KydeYi/1)

```
while (!word.matches("\\w{3,}")) {  // don't match more than 3
   //
}

// -- OR --

while (word.matches("\\w{0,3}")) {  // match between 0 and 3 is also correct
   //
}
```